How to synchronise async runtimes
We have a Python application that is implemented with the async runtime. Now we want to integrate a C library (with Cython) that runs its own event loop (e.g. epoll).
How can we integrate these two different runtime mechanisms. Is there a general pattern to synchronise these two codebases?
Eventually we might replace the Python code with Rust. So using a language-independent pattern would be nice.

The problem with co-operative multitasking is that all the code needs to co-operate. You can't use a library that blocks, such as the one you are asking about.

The pyo3 crate is the de-facto library for interfacing with Rust from Python and has substantial documentation for async between them: see Async / Await in their User Guide and the pyo3-asyncio helper library documentation. The implementation does use a separate event loop on the Rust side. You'll likely not need to do anything custom if your use-case isn't too niche.

Thanks, @kmdreko. I came across pyo3. But our application would be either Python or Rust (together with C). pyo3 could be of help for porting the app from Python to Rust. But we would need to have the right async patterns in place already before we start the migration.

Does this answer your question? How can I integrate asyncio with an external event loop?

@relent95 Thanks for the hint. This gives me some pointers to a solution for our problem.
